# triggers based on time plsql

Tags: mysql, sql, plsql

is it possible to create triggers or events based on time like if the time is 02:00 then delete a record from a table and insert it into some other table, so that clean up audit logs or create backup or execute some procedures can be executed. If it is possible please provide a sample example.

(EDIT)

I have created the below event but it is not working what am I missing here

mysql> CREATE EVENT myevent ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE DO UPDATE test.test SET number = 11;

here test is a table that contains number as column_name

Comment: And it's supposed to work with both MySQL and Oracle?

Comment: I wanted to see an example of MySql, and if anyone knows even Oracle an example would be better for future reference

Comment: Triggers fire on events (i.e. insert, delete or update). So the trigger is executed when the corresponding event occurs. Anyway you surely can write your trigger (like nearly any other code) that what it should do depends on `sysdate`.

Comment: @evilive can you provide any sample or link on how to write triggers based on 
sysdate in Mysql database

Comment: Use a scheduler to do the task. DBMS_SCHEDULER or DBMS_JOB depending on the database version. You could also schedule it at OS level.

Comment: In mysql you can use the event scheduler http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> create triggers based on time events like if the time is 02:00

Don't use triggers, use [DBMS_SCHEDULER](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_sched.htm) or [DBMS_JOB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_job.htm#BABHCBFD) whichever is applicable depending on the database version.

This creates a daily run job at 2am

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_SCHEDULER.create_job (
    job_name        => 'daily_report_run',
    job_type        => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
    job_action      => 'daily_run',
    start_date      => SYSTIMESTAMP,
    repeat_interval => 'freq=hourly; byhour=2',
    end_date        => NULL,
    enabled         => TRUE);
END;
/
dbms_scheduler.create_schedule('daily_run', repeat_interval =>
  'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=02');
```

Which then runs 'daily_report' procedure

```
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_PROGRAM (
   program_name => 'daily_report_job',
   program_type   => 'STORED_PROCEDURE',
   program_action    => 'daily_report',
   enabled   => TRUE);
```

Comment: is there any scheduler or jobs for mysql ?

Comment: mysql> CREATE EVENT myevent     ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 MINUTE     DO       UPDATE test.test SET number = 11;

Comment: above is the event that I had created but it is not updating the expected column value to the Mysql databse am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: that really should be posted as a separate question